Noise modelling with Jordan's lemma
In many self-testing protocols / quantum verification protocols, one encounters the so-called "Jordan Lemma":
Given two dichotomic Hermitian finite or countably infinite dimensional matrices $\tilde{A},\tilde{B}$ with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. There exists a choice of basis in which both $\tilde{A},\tilde{B}$ take a block diagonal form. Within this basis, they may be written as a direct sum of countably infinite or finitely many $2 \times 2$  matrices $\tilde{A}_j, \tilde{B}_j$ as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\tilde{A}=\bigoplus_j \,\tilde{A}_j(\theta_j) = \bigoplus_j \cos (\theta_j) X + \sin (\theta_j) Z,\\
    &\tilde{B}=\bigoplus_j \, \tilde{B}_j(\theta_j)=\bigoplus_j \cos (\theta_j) X - \sin (\theta_j) Z
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $X$ denotes Pauli-$X$ matrix, $Z$ denotes Pauli-$Z$ matrix and $\theta_j$ denotes the angle between the projectors onto the $j^\mathrm{th}$ and $j^\mathrm{th}+1$ eigenspace in with $\tilde{A}_j$ and $\tilde{A}_{j+1}$ are block diagonal, respectively.
I understand what the lemma does and says and how it can be useful, namely, you can write imperfect Pauli-X and -Z with unknown degrees of freedom in this block diagonal form.
I was just wondering why we can still assume that the imperfect measurements are dichotomic. Is there a physical reason for this? Why are my imperfect observables now so degenerate that although they have a high dimension, they still only have two eigenvalues?
